# Bad dropdown arrow styling on firefox and safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, sass, safari

My dropdowns look like the left on **Chrome**, but looks like the right on **Firefox** and **Safari**

[image] [image]

**How can I style my dropdown to look like the chrome version on safari and firefox?** I don't like the grey background for the caret that shows on firefox
(I would also like to move the caret symbol a little bit to the left)

---

This is my `css` and `html` for the dropdown. You can click "Run code snippet" on firefox and see that it looks like the one on the right.

```css
select{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
    border: 0;
}

select:active, select:focus{
   outline: none;
}
```

```html
<select type="dropdown">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And what is the element? A select?

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, I updated my `css`. There's also a [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dzuq80gr/14/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance

Comment: Use ```CSS padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;``` instead of defining all sides to save space

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should reset default styling and add your custom style that is uniform across browsers. This below snippet should help

```css
select{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  border: 0;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: right .7em top 50%;
  background-size: .65em auto;
}
```

```html
<select type="dropdown">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Read more from this blog post: https://css-tricks.com/styling-a-select-like-its-2019/

Answer (score 0):

```css
select{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    padding-top: 0.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
    padding-right: 1.5rem; /* increased to make space for arrow*/
    padding-left: 0.5rem;
    border: 0;
    appearance: none; /* remove default arrow */
    outline: none; /* looks better without outline */
}


.custom-select {
  position: relative; /* container for pseudo element */
  display: inline-block; /* make width to fit content */
}

.custom-select::after {
  content: '⌄';
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  right: 10%;
  top: -10%;
  pointer-events: none; /* let clicks go through */
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-select">
  <select type="dropdown">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is a really easy and effective way, consistent on every browser.

HTML:

- Add a wrapper on select element

CSS:

- Set `appearance:none` and increase `padding-right` accordingly on select element.
- Set the wrapper `position: relative;` and `display: inline-block;` to make it as a container for an absolute positioned pseudo element.
- Style and position the `wrapper::after` element how you prefer, with `pointer-events:none` so that your clicks will go through it, opening the select.